# Adding SPM support to Mixed Language CocoaPod results in No Such Module

Tags: swift, objective-c, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

Since SPM doesn't support mixed language targets, I have to split the ObjectiveC files into a separate target.

```
let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyPackage",
            targets: ["MyPackage"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyPackage",
            dependencies: ["ObjCTarget"]),
        .target(name: "ObjCTarget"),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MyPackageTests",
            dependencies: ["MyPackage"]),
    ]
)
```

This requires me to `import ObjCTarget` in the Swift files of the main `MyPackage` target. When I add it everything works fine for SPM.

However, if I wish to continue with support for CocoaPods I get `No Such Module` error since Cocoapods bundles them into one target. What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
#if !COCOAPODS
import ObjCTarget
#endif
```

Works with both managers now.